# expression evaluation using stack in java

Tags: java

My program is working with expression like  12 + 3 * 45.But Its not working expression like 12*4+(7/2). please give correction in my code.I am attaching my code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class EvaluateString
{
    public static int evaluate(String expression)
    {
        char[] tokens = expression.toCharArray();

         // Stack for numbers: 'values'
        Stack<Integer> values = new Stack<Integer>();

        // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
        Stack<Character> ops = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
             // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
            if (tokens[i] == ' ')
                continue;

            // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
            if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
            {
                StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                // There may be more than one digits in number
                while (i < tokens.length && tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
                    sbuf.append(tokens[i++]);
                values.push(Integer.parseInt(sbuf.toString()));
            }

            // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
            else if (tokens[i] == '(')
                ops.push(tokens[i]);

            // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
            else if (tokens[i] == ')')
            {
                while (ops.peek() != '(')
                  values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
                ops.pop();
            }

            // Current token is an operator.
            else if (tokens[i] == '+' || tokens[i] == '-' ||
                     tokens[i] == '*' || tokens[i] == '/')
            {
                // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
                // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
                // to top two elements in values stack
                while (!ops.empty() && hasPrecedence(tokens[i], ops.peek()))
                  values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));

                // Push current token to 'ops'.
                ops.push(tokens[i]);
            }
        }

        // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
        // ops to remaining values
        while (!ops.empty())
            values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));

        // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
        return values.pop();
    }

    // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
    // otherwise returns false.
    public static boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
    {
        if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
            return false;
        if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    // A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a' 
    // and 'b'. Return the result.
    public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
    {
        switch (op)
        {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
            if (b == 0)
                throw new
                UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot divide by zero");
            return a / b;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Driver method to test above methods
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(EvaluateString.evaluate("10 + 2 * 6"));

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a debugger to set a break point and step through your code. Does your algorithm work on paper? If you trace through with the expected input do you get the expected output? If so then use a debugger to find out what path your code is taking and where you went wrong. If you don't have this written out on paper it would help you quite a bit to try it that way first.

Comment: I used the debugger.In case of 1+2 expression. its skipping + operator. Because of this code // There may be more than one digits in number
            while (i < tokens.length && tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
                sbuf.append(tokens[i++]);
            values.push(Integer.parseInt(sbuf.toString()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your block which parses digits:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    // ...
    if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
    {
        StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
        // There may be more than one digits in number
        while (i < tokens.length && tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
            sbuf.append(tokens[i++]);
        values.push(Integer.parseInt(sbuf.toString()));
    }
    // ...
}
```

Let's assume our tokens are {'1', '+', '2'} and your initial `i` value is 0. We're entering the `if`-body (as `tokens[0] == 1`), declare an `sbuf` variable and again make exactly the same check for that `i` (but we're inside the `if`-block with the same check as your `while` condition). So, we're going inside while loop, append `tokens[0]` to `sbuf` and **increase** our `i`. So now `i` is 1 and points to `+`, while condition is `false`, we parse `"1"` into 1 and add it to `values`. But now the next iteration of outer for-loop begins and the `i` value will be `2`. So, we totally missed `+` as we incremented it's value inside while-loop but haven't processed it in any way.

Now let's find an alternative approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    // ...
    if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9') {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(tokens[i]);
        // There may be more than one digits in number
        while (i + 1 < tokens.length && tokens[i + 1] >= '0' && tokens[i + 1] <= '9') {
            sb.append(tokens[++i]);
        }
        values.push(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
    }
    // ...
}
```

This approach adds the current value right after declaring `sb` (I changed `StringBuffer` to `StringBuilder` as there is no need to use thread-safe `StringBuffer` implementation). Next we're checking the next value of `i` without incrementing. If it is also a number we're incrementing `i` and appending it to `sb`. Otherwise no changes to `i` happens and it will still point to the same value (1 in our case). Now your outer for-loop will increment it and you'll correctly process `+`.

By the way, if you're writing parser it's better not only return `values.pop()` but also check that `values.size() == 1`. If the size is not one then the expression either is not correct or has not been parsed correctly.

Comment: Thank u so much. I appreciate ur code.But my code is not working for unary operator.what are changes in my code?plz help me

Comment: @AniketShinde right now your code is working only with binary operators. To support unary you have to add another if-else branch and add another `applyOp` method which takes a value and operator. Though that was not the original question, try it first by yourself and in case of difficulties ask another question with your particular problem. If current question is resolved and code works properly with binary operators feel free to upvote/accept an answer

Comment: right now it's working with binary operator..thank you so much

Comment: This code is working fine. thank u for helping me.Can please give me code for unary operator ( -).please